# How to increase the product quantity by one in the point of sale module in Odoo v9?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

After click on product in Odoo POS the quantity should increases by one.

This is the original function in the file `point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js`

```js
orderline_change: function(line){
     this.rerender_orderline(line);
     this.update_summary();
},
```

Now I want call this function from my module to increase the product quantity by one (when `Ctrl + Left arrow` are pressed):

```js
//OrderWidget
screens.OrderWidget.include({
    renderElement: function(){
        this._super();
        var self = this;


        //CTRL + Left arrow
        $.ctrl('37', function() {                
            var order_line = self.pos.get_order().get_last_orderline();
            self.rerender_orderline(order_line);
            self.update_summary();
        });
    },    
});
```

In my examle I get correct line id but the quantity does not change!
Any solution?

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: You have to trigger event. After triggering you get your changed qty.

Comment: @ChesuCR On my click (Ctrl + Arrow left) I want for selected product increase qty +1

Comment: @Keval Mehta How use trigger event in my example. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the set_quantity() method of the order line object to update line 
 quantity.

```
//OrderWidget
screens.OrderWidget.include({
   renderElement: function(){
        this._super();
        var self = this;

        //CTRL + Left arrow
        $.ctrl('37', function() {
            var order_line = self.pos.get_order().get_last_orderline();
            order_line.set_quantity(order_line.get_quantity() + 1);
        });
    }, 
});
```